# Discrete math help prove that they are equivalent

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove that $X$ and $Y$ are equal.

Rantional Set Q1 = {n/m : n, m\in \mathbb{Z}, m\neq 0}. $$

Rational Set Q2 = { a/b : a, b\in \mathbb{Z}, b> 0, \gcd(a,b) =1} .$$

Comment: You show that every element in $X$ is in $Y, X\subset Y$ then you show that every element in $Y$ is also in $X, Y\subset X.$  if   $X\subset Y$ and $Y\subset X$ then $X=Y$

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can decipher this question, it boils down to the idea that any fraction $n/m$ where $m\neq 0$ can be turned, through cancellation of common factors and if need be multiplication by $-1$ of both numerator and denominator, into a fraction of the form $a/b$, where $a\in\mathbb{Z},b\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a$ and $b$ have no common factors.